# phpDoc PDF templates

Tags: php, pdf, phpdoc

I'm very pleased with the various HTML templates available for phpDocs. I was wondering about additional PDF templates for my PHP application which I'm writing as a capstone project and would like to include as a supplement to my paper. The default PDF template seems to ignore a few @tags, and has a lot of issues with inappropriate whitespace.

If there are no user-submitted PDF templates elsewhere, where might I look to learn how to edit the default to, for example, adjust the whitespace issues and change the font/font-size, etc.? Or, is there a better alterative to phpDoc that specializes in the PDF format? Some of the HTML ones are very nice-looking, but have no options to print as an entire document.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a last ditch option, you might give wkhtmltopdf [1] a try.  It sounds like it can take your HTML docs (as generated by phpDocumentor, DocBlox, etc) and transform them into a PDF for you.

[1] -- http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/